# Basic First Law of Thermodynamics Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

$2$ kg of water is heated by stirring. If this process raises the temperature of water from $15^{\circ}$ C to $25^{\circ}$ C, how much work, in joules, was done to the water by the stirring?

---

I calculated $W = Q = mc\Delta T = (2000)(4.18)(10) = 83,600 J$.

Is this right? I don't know if my original claim that $W = Q$ is right.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first law is simply $\Delta U = Q - W$. For an incompressible substance (e.g., water), you have $\Delta U = mc \Delta T$. Now, the problem says nothing about heat transfer into the water, only that its temperature raises. I'd say this is is a clear hint that $Q=0$, and the work is done on the water adiabatically.

Answer (score 1):

Drew's correct answer directly addresses the question about the work done by stirring the fluid. There is an additional point in your question that I feel would be important to clarify.

First principle *defines*  $\Delta U$ as the sum of the incoming heat and work (there is freedom about the convention for signs, but, at the and of the day, work which is performed *on* the system increases its internal energy). So, internal energy may increase with different combination of incoming work and/or heat. Unfortunately, in everyday language we do not have a special word for indicating an increase of internal energy and we use the verb "to heat" even if the "heating" is not due to a difference of temperature but to work done by friction forces.

Therefore, stirring a fluid means that some work has been done and, when the system relaxes to equilibrium, it has entirely converted into internal energy.